# Confused about Gauss's Law for parallel plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I am having trouble understanding Gauss's Law. Suppose we wish to find the electric field strength between two parallel plates with charge density $\sigma$. I know it should be $E=\sigma/(2\epsilon_0)$.

But if we place a cylinder between the plates with base parallel to the plates such that the cylinder does not intersect the plates, then the charge enclosed is $0$ and the flux is $2EA$ where $A$ is the area of the base of the cylinder. Thus by Gauss's Law, $2EA=0$, which gives $E=0$. What is the error in my understanding?

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is wrong. The flux is not $2EA$. Rather, is $-EA + EA = 0$. The reason is because Gauss's law involves the dot product of $E$ and $dA$. The direction of $dA$ is the **way out of the cylinder**. When the electric field goes through the bottom of the cylinder, the electric field is in the **opposite direction** of the area vector, so the electric flux is $-EA$. When the electric field vector exits the cylinder, it is in the same direction as the area vector, so the electric flux is $EA$. Hence, the net electric flux is $-EA + EA = 0$, not $2EA$. Hence, $0 = 0$, not $2EA = 0$. To solve for the electric field, take a cylinder which goes through one plate. Then, the electric field goes **outside the cylinder** through the inner base, so the electric field is $EA$. The charge enclosed is $\sigma A$, so $EA = \sigma A/\epsilon_0 $, and thus $E = \sigma /\epsilon_0$.

Answer (score 0):

For a Gaussian surface between the two plates, the total flux through the surface is zero.  For the particular surface you give, *all* of the electric field lines crossing one of the circular faces cross the other face *but* in an opposite sense.

This is because the *outward* normal vector for one face of the cylinder is *opposite* in direction to the outward normal for the other face.

In other words, there is a sign difference; there is $EA$ flux through one face and $-EA$ flux through the other so the total flux is zero.

---

As an aside, if the (infinite) parallel plates have the same charge density $\sigma$, the electric field between the plates is actually zero.

If one plate has charge density $\sigma$ and the other has charge density $-\sigma$, then the [electric field between the plates](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html) is $E = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}$, not $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$